# .Net consuming iSeries web service

Tags: .net, wcf, soapui, fiddler, ibm-midrange

I am trying to consume an iseries web service with .Net. I have had success communicating with other web services on the iSeries, but with this particular one, I am having a very strange issue.

Here is the wsdl of the web service from the iSeries.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:tns="http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ZCntInfFr"
targetNamespace="http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/">
        <xsd:element name="GetContactInfoOperation">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="ShipToAcct" minOccurs="1"
                        maxOccurs="1">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:length value="6"></xsd:length>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="GetContactInfoOperationResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Contacts"
                        type="tns:ContactsType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:complexType name="ContactDataType">
            <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:element name="ContactType" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="0"></xsd:minLength>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="5"></xsd:maxLength>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="ContactTypeDesc" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="0"></xsd:minLength>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="50"></xsd:maxLength>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="ContactName" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="0"></xsd:minLength>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="25"></xsd:maxLength>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="ContactTitle" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="0"></xsd:minLength>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="20"></xsd:maxLength>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="ContactEmail" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="0"></xsd:minLength>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="128"></xsd:maxLength>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="ContactPhone" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="0"></xsd:minLength>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="15"></xsd:maxLength>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="ContactExtension" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="0"></xsd:minLength>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="5"></xsd:maxLength>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="ContactFax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="0"></xsd:minLength>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="15"></xsd:maxLength>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="ContactsType">
            <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:element name="ContactData" type="tns:ContactDataType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="GetContactInfoOperationRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetContactInfoOperation"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetContactInfoOperationResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetContactInfoOperationResponse"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ZCntInfFr">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetContactInfoOperation">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:GetContactInfoOperationRequest"></wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:GetContactInfoOperationResponse"></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="ZCntInfFrSOAP" type="tns:ZCntInfFr">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="GetContactInfoOperation">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/GetContactInfoOperation" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ZCntInfFr">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:ZCntInfFrSOAP" name="ZCntInfFrSOAP">
        <soap:address location="http://server:8181/myrxs/ZCntInfFr" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

When I test this in SoapUI, here is the request/response I receive:

SoapUI Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:zcn="http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <zcn:GetContactInfoOperation>
         <ShipToAcct>099039</ShipToAcct>
      </zcn:GetContactInfoOperation>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SoapUI Response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:zcn="http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <zcn:GetContactInfoOperationResponse>
         <Contacts>
            <ContactData>
               <ContactType>ADMIN</ContactType>
               <ContactTypeDesc>Administrator</ContactTypeDesc>
               <ContactName>Name</ContactName>
               <ContactTitle/>
               <ContactEmail>Email</ContactEmail>
               <ContactPhone/>
               <ContactExtension/>
               <ContactFax/>
            </ContactData>
         </Contacts>
      </zcn:GetContactInfoOperationResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The response is exactly how I would expect it. Notice I am getting back one contact, which is correct.

When I call the iSeries web service from .Net here is the request/response I see when looking at Fiddler:

.Net Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <GetContactInfoOperation xmlns="http://www.mysitye.com/ZCntInfFr/">
            <ShipToAcct xmlns="">099039</ShipToAcct>
        </GetContactInfoOperation>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

.Net Response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:zcn="http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <zcn:GetContactInfoOperationResponse>
     <Contacts>
     </Contacts>
    </zcn:GetContactInfoOperationResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In this case, when I call it from .Net I receive an empty  node. No contacts.

For completeness, here is proxy class I created from svcutil using:

```
svcutil /n:*,Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact /o:ContactProxy /s http://server:8181/ZCntInfFr.wsdl
```

Class:

```
namespace Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact
{
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/", ConfigurationName = "Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.ZCntInfFr")]
    public interface ZCntInfFr
    {
        // CODEGEN: Parameter 'Contacts' requires additional schema information that cannot be captured using the parameter mode. The specific attribute is 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute'.
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/GetContactInfoOperation", ReplyAction = "*")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
        [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name = "Contacts")]
        Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationResponse GetContactInfoOperation(Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationRequest request);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/GetContactInfoOperation", ReplyAction = "*")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationResponse> GetContactInfoOperationAsync(Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationRequest request);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.0.30319.33440")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/")]
    public partial class ContactDataType
    {

        private string[] itemsField;

        private ItemsChoiceType[] itemsElementNameField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ContactEmail", typeof(string), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ContactExtension", typeof(string), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ContactFax", typeof(string), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ContactName", typeof(string), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ContactPhone", typeof(string), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ContactTitle", typeof(string), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ContactType", typeof(string), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ContactTypeDesc", typeof(string), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
        public string[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName", Order = 1)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsElementNameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsElementNameField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.0.30319.33440")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/", IncludeInSchema = false)]
    public enum ItemsChoiceType
    {

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":ContactEmail")]
        ContactEmail,

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":ContactExtension")]
        ContactExtension,

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":ContactFax")]
        ContactFax,

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":ContactName")]
        ContactName,

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":ContactPhone")]
        ContactPhone,

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":ContactTitle")]
        ContactTitle,

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":ContactType")]
        ContactType,

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":ContactTypeDesc")]
        ContactTypeDesc,
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.0.30319.33440")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/")]
    public partial class ContactsType
    {

        private ContactDataType[] contactDataField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ContactData", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        public ContactDataType[] ContactData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.contactDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.contactDataField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "GetContactInfoOperation", WrapperNamespace = "http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/", IsWrapped = true)]
    public partial class GetContactInfoOperationRequest
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/", Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string ShipToAcct;

        public GetContactInfoOperationRequest()
        {
        }

        public GetContactInfoOperationRequest(string ShipToAcct)
        {
            this.ShipToAcct = ShipToAcct;
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "GetContactInfoOperationResponse", WrapperNamespace = "http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/", IsWrapped = true)]
    public partial class GetContactInfoOperationResponse
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://example.com/ZCntInfFr/", Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.ContactsType Contacts;

        public GetContactInfoOperationResponse()
        {
        }

        public GetContactInfoOperationResponse(Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.ContactsType Contacts)
        {
            this.Contacts = Contacts;
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public interface ZCntInfFrChannel : Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.ZCntInfFr, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
    {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class ZCntInfFrClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.ZCntInfFr>, Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.ZCntInfFr
    {

        public ZCntInfFrClient()
        {
        }

        public ZCntInfFrClient(string endpointConfigurationName) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
        {
        }

        public ZCntInfFrClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public ZCntInfFrClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public ZCntInfFrClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationResponse Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.ZCntInfFr.GetContactInfoOperation(Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationRequest request)
        {
            return base.Channel.GetContactInfoOperation(request);
        }

        public Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.ContactsType GetContactInfoOperation(string ShipToAcct)
        {
            Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationRequest inValue = new Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationRequest();
            inValue.ShipToAcct = ShipToAcct;
            Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationResponse retVal = ((Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.ZCntInfFr)(this)).GetContactInfoOperation(inValue);
            return retVal.Contacts;
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationResponse> Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.ZCntInfFr.GetContactInfoOperationAsync(Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationRequest request)
        {
            return base.Channel.GetContactInfoOperationAsync(request);
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationResponse> GetContactInfoOperationAsync(string ShipToAcct)
        {
            Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationRequest inValue = new Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.GetContactInfoOperationRequest();
            inValue.ShipToAcct = ShipToAcct;
            return ((Services.Web.Proxy.ISeriesContact.ZCntInfFr)(this)).GetContactInfoOperationAsync(inValue);
        }
    }
}
```

I have enabled WCF tracing and nothing is sticking out in the .svclog file. I have been googling like mad and have seen that there might be some issues with minOccurs in the WSDL. My thought is that perhaps it is something to do with the deserialization process in .Net.

As a side note, and an exercise, I was able to call the SOAP service using the WebClient object and I retrieved the correct raw XML with the contact in it. This also leads me to my thought that something is going on with deserialization.

I also tried to generate the proxy with wsdl.exe but I still go back an empty clients node.

One other thing I should mention is that when I add the reference to the iSeries web service to Service References in my project, I get exactly the same results: No contacts.

Any help, nudge, advice, or direction would be greatly appreciated. I have been working on this for two days and I am still not fully understanding what is going on here.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you debugged the iSeries side of things to see what it thinks it's receiving as a request?  Sounds like the issue is there, not in your request.

Comment: Yes. The person working on the iSeries has debugged her side and she is returning the one contact, which I can see using SoapUI but not when I consume it from .Net.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that on the iSeries they can see the data returned is what you expect, but what is actually returned is different.  Either the iSeries is returning one contact or not.  I'd sit down with them and double check and not just "assume" on either side.

Comment: How does that account for when I call the web service in SoapUI I see the contact information being returned?

Comment: It doesn't.  But, when you use your .net app to request the data, that is when the iSeries person needs to debug and make for sure it's sending the proper XML back (and if not why.. is your XML not formatted properly?  She should be able to capture your exact request as it comes in).  If she says it's sending a contact and you're not receiving one, one of you is wrong.  See my point?  I don't think there's anything that will remove XML container data in limbo.

Comment: Are you using the same user profile for SoapUI and .NET?  Imagine if the .NET connection were using a test schema.  It'd connect OK, but there wouldn't be a contact for the production order that you tried with SoapUI.  That's my guess.

Comment: I'm using the same url in SoapUI for testing and for generating the proxy via svcutil

Comment: I believe the answer lies in the requests (see above). See the differences between the namespaces? The SoapUI namespace is in the Envelope while the .Net generated one puts it on the operation. Why is there a discrepancy. I have called other web services from the iSeries before and have not had this issue.

Answer (score 1):

So a shout out to bvstone.

It turns out that the iSeries developer was hand parsing the requests. So even though the request generation from SoapUI and from .Net were functionally equivalent, the structure was different. This was not handled properly in the iSeries code.

I'm no expert on the iSeries but I have suggested that we use standard xml libraries, if they exist for the iSeries to parse xml requests correctly.

Thanks, bvstone for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed many services exposing and consuming data in iSeries and I seriously recommend Scott Klement [HTTPAPI](http://www.scottklement.com/httpapi/) for this job. Give it a try you won't regret it.